# Unit Testing of .NET Add-In for Microsoft Office

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, add-in

Has anyone got any suggestions for unit testing a Managed Application Add-In for Office?  I'm using NUnit but I had the same issues with MSTest.

The problem is that there is a .NET assembly loaded inside the Office application (in my case, Word) and I need a reference to that instance of the .NET assembly.  I can't just instantiate the object because it wouldn't then have an instance of Word to do things to.

Now, I can use the Application.COMAddIns("Name of addin").Object interface to get a reference, but that gets me a COM object that is returned through the RequestComAddInAutomationService.  My solution so far is that for that object to have proxy methods for every method in the real .NET object that I want to test (all set under conditional-compilation so they disappear in the released version).

The COM object (a  VB.NET class) actually has a reference to the instance of the real add-in, but I tried just returning that to NUnit and I got a nice p/Invoke error:

System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException : This remoting proxy has no channel sink which means either the server has no registered server channels that are listening, or this application has no suitable client channel to talk to the server.
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(IMethodCallMessage reqMcmMsg, Boolean useDispatchMessage, Int32 callType)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(IMessage reqMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

I tried making the main add-in COM visible and the error changes:

System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

While I have a work-around, it's messy and puts lots of test code in the real project instead of the test project - which isn't really the way NUnit is meant to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I resolved it.

1. Just about everything in my add-in runs from the Click method of a button in the UI.  I have changed all those Click methods to consist only of a simple, parameterless call.
2. I then created a new file (Partial Class) called EntryPoint that had lots of very short Friend Subs, each of which was usually one or two calls to parameterised worker functions, so that all the Click methods just called into this file.  So, for example, there's a function that opens a standard document and calls a "save as" into our DMS.   The function takes a parameter of which document to open, and there are a couple of dozen standard documents that we use.

So I have

```
Private Sub btnMemo_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean) Handles btnMemo.Click
    DocMemo()
End Sub
```

in the ThisAddin and then

```
Friend Sub DocMemo()
    OpenDocByNumber("Prec", 8862, 1)
End Sub
```

in my new EntryPoints file.

3. I add a new AddInUtilities file which has

   Public Interface IAddInUtilities

`#If DEBUG Then`

```
Sub DocMemo()
```

`#End If`

```
End Interface


Public Class AddInUtilities
    Implements IAddInUtilities
    Private Addin as ThisAddIn
```

`#If DEBUG Then`

```
Public Sub DocMemo() Implements IAddInUtilities.DocMemo
    Addin.DocMemo()
End Sub
```

`#End If`

```
 Friend Sub New(ByRef theAddin as ThisAddIn)
     Addin=theAddin
 End Sub
 End Class
```

4. I go to the ThisAddIn file and add in

   Private utilities As AddInUtilities

   Protected Overrides Function RequestComAddInAutomationService() As Object
       If utilities Is Nothing Then
           utilities = New AddInUtilities(Me)
       End If
       Return utilities
   End Function

And now it's possible to test the DocMemo() function in EntryPoints using NUnit, something like this:

```
<TestFixture()> Public Class Numbering

Private appWord As Word.Application
Private objMacros As Object

<TestFixtureSetUp()> Public Sub LaunchWord()
    appWord = New Word.Application
    appWord.Visible = True

    Dim AddIn As COMAddIn = Nothing
    Dim AddInUtilities As IAddInUtilities
    For Each tempAddin As COMAddIn In appWord.COMAddIns
        If tempAddin.Description = "CobbettsMacrosVsto" Then
            AddIn = tempAddin
        End If
    Next
    AddInUtilities = AddIn.Object
    objMacros = AddInUtilities.TestObject


End Sub

<Test()> Public Sub DocMemo()


    objMacros.DocMemo()
End Sub

<TestFixtureTearDown()> Public Sub TearDown()
    appWord.Quit(False)
End Sub

End Class
```

The only thing you can't then unit test are the actual Click events, because you're calling into EntryPoints in a different way, ie through the RequestComAddInAutomationService interface rather than through the event handlers.

But it works!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the various mocking frameworks [NMock](http://www.nmock.org/), [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), etc. to fake the behavior of Office in your tests.

Comment: @RichardGadsden Yup thats right & I've done it for Excel using NSubstitute it wasn't that hard in the end.